# Notice: Undefined index: mappedBy

Tags: symfony, yaml, relation

I don't understand relations with Doctrine2. I'm trying to follow the documentation but it lacks proper explanation.

I have **Client**, **Material**, **Budget** and **Orders** tables. The **Budget** form lists data from the first two tables and I need to relate both of them to **Order**, that will store the client's id and all the material's id he needs. So, following the docs, I reached this result in my `Orders.orm.yml`:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Orders:
    type: entity
    table: orders
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\OrdersRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        materialQuantity:
            type: integer
            column: material_quantity
        materialPrice:
            type: decimal
            column: material_price
        dateCreated:
            type: datetime
            column: date_created
    oneToOne:
        clientId:
            targetEntity: Client
            joinColumn:
                name: client_id
                referencedToColumnName: id
        order:
            targetEntity: Orders
            joinColumn:
                name: order
                referencedToColumnName: id
    manyToOne:
        materialId:
            targetEntity: Material
            joinColumn:
                name: material_id
                mappedBy: materials
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

My `Material.orm.yml`:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Material:
    type: entity
    table: material
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\MaterialRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            column: name
            length: 255
        description:
            type: string
            column: description
            length: 255
        quantity:
            type: integer
            column: quantity
        price:
            type: integer
            column: price
    oneToMany:
        materials:
            targetEntity: 
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And `Budget.orm.yml`

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Budget:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\BudgetRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        clientName:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: client_name
        materials:
            type: array
        address:
            type: string
            length: 255
        installments:
            type: integer
        checkDays:
            type: integer
            column: check_days
        totalValue:
            type: decimal
            column: total_value
        order:
            type: integer
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

In my home page, I have a listing of the last five data from all 3 tables, and I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: mappedBy

Answer (score 1):

In a *oneToMany* relationship, you should use the `mappedBy` option. In a *manyToOne* relationship, you use the `inversedBy` option.

Comment: Although this is true, error there wasn't caused by that particular "mismatch" and so this isn't a valid answer at all

Answer (score 0):

The YAML syntax should look like this:

```
table: orders
repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\OrdersRepository
...
    manyToOne:
        materialId:
            targetEntity: Material
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                material_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
```

Note that one would normally expect there to be a ManyToMany relationship between Client and Order unless a client will have one and only one order.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm feeling lost in the name used after the relation declaration, what are these names? Based on what?

Comment: The names (e.g, cascade:, fetch:, etc.) were generated by Doctrine when creating mapping info from an existing database.  They may be ignored.  The important point is the level of indentation.  In the example provided, `inversedBy` has the same level as `targetEntity`.  The error you received was likely due to `mappedBy` being one level too deep.